# Hide/Show a Label in custom cell in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following cell in `TableView`.

Initially, I assign height `0` for `Promotion` Label and its value which is hardcoded $10.

Whenever user clicks on `Promotion` button and I am making height bigger to show `Promotion` and its value and assign height `30`.

However, the only changes that I see, height of the cell is getting bigger and spaces between first and second label is getting bigger, but I cannot able to see `promotion label`.

**here is my code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

  static NSString *cellLastIdentifier = @"lastcell";
  LastTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellLastIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
       cell = [[LastTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellLastIdentifier];
   cell.subTotalLbl.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"$ %.02f", subtotal ];
   cell.salesLbl.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"+$ %.02f", tax ];
   if(isPromotionApplied)
   {
     cell.promotionLabelHeight.constant = 30;
     cell.promotionValueLblHeight.constant = 30;
     cell.promotionValueLbl.text = @"120";
    }
   return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(isPromotionApplied)
        return 140.0;
    else
         return 100.0;
}

- (void)applyPromoCode : (double)percent
{
   isPromotionApplied = YES;
   NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sharedData.orderItems count] inSection:0];
   NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
   [self.checkOutTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

**LastTableViewCell storyboard**

[image]

Comment: is that all custom cell in screenshot ?

Comment: Actually, I am using it as a last cell item in the tableView.

Comment: applyPromoCode is this IBAction ?

Comment: actually, `promotionBtn` action calls that method.

Comment: ok then what happens here can you explain me ?

Comment: Initially, SubTotal and Sales taxes are visible as a default. Let's assume that you have promotion code to apply. When user clicks on PromotionBtn and then AlertView appears and you put promotion code and after the validation, it calls applyPromoCode method.. In that method, I am refreshing only the last cell which has subtotal, sales and promotion. but promotion initially hidden and I am making cell height bigger and display promotion, but promotion does not show up..

Comment: in the above code handle else conditions :
if(isPromotionApplied)
   {
     cell.promotionLbl.hidden = NO;
     cell.promotionValueLbl.hidden = NO;
     cell.promotionValueLbl.text = @"120";
    }else{ 
    cell.promotionLbl.hidden = YES;
     cell.promotionValueLbl.hidden = YES;
 }

Comment: In the storyboard, I am hiding them.

Comment: try to reload using this :  [self.checkOutTableView reloadData];

Comment: Don't hide promotionLbl and promotionLbl. On click, expand the size as you are doing now. Check if this works

Comment: I am not hiding it anymore, only give heights 0 initially

Comment: Why are you not using `autolayout` and `aumaticdimension`? Using this you  wont need to calculate height or anything.

Comment: Load as it is...the way it is visible in your nib or storyboard...If it is visible in there but you can't get it on device..there is some problem with the constraints.Else check the logic where you are hiding/showing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the constraints your sales tax label should have vertical bottom constraint to promotion label and promotion label should have vertical bottom constraint to custom cell.

Now create a IBOutlet of height constraint of the promotion label and instead of show hide set the height to 0 and 20

heres a short demo 
https://github.com/harshalrj25/stackoverFlowAnswers

Comment: Please see my code, updated based on your suggestion but still no luck.

Comment: wait i wil send you a demo

Comment: i have added a demo link in my answer

Answer (score 1):

For this you should set the auto layout constraint between the labels and also set the height constraint for the `promotionlbl`.

Then take an outlet of the height constraint of the `promotionlbl` and initially set the constraint's constant to 0 and when you want to show the `promotionlbl`, then again set height constant as per your need.

Comment: try to reload using this :  [self.checkOutTableView reloadData];

Comment: I am reloading as follows      `[self.checkOutTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

Comment: Please see my code, updated based on your suggestion but still no luck.